# how can I create view from unrelated tables

Tags: php, codeigniter

[image: click here to view tables]

I have three tables, for Product, sells, and purchased. Products relate with sells and also relates with Purchased.

How can I produce a view as shown above using Codeigniter?

```
$this->db->select('*')
            ->from('product p')
            ->join('sells s','p.id=s.pid', 'left');

$query = $this->db->get();

 return $query->result_array(); 


 $this->db->select('*')
            ->from('product p')
            ->join('purchased d','p.id=d.pid', 'left');

$query = $this->db->get();

 return $query->result_array();
```

Comment: How are these unrelated is `product.id` not `pid` ?  `I have three tables, for Product, sells, and purchased. Products relate with sells and also relates with Purchased.`  Just combine them with the Join.

Comment: There are two relations visible, @Claudius. **pid** and **date/Date**, if you don't want to use pid, you can still use the date in the join.

Comment: Table products related to sells by Pid, also table products related to purchased by pid, but there is no relationship between sells and purchased, i want to produce a view as shown and ordered by date

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work.  Note, I used the case as shown in your table diagram so you should adjust as needed.

```
$this->db->select('Product.id, Product.Name, Sells.Pid AS Spid, Sells.Items_sold, Sells.Date AS Sells_date');
$this->db->select('Purchased.Pid, Purchased.Items_purchased, Purchased.date AS Purchased_date');
$this->db->from('Product');
$this->db->join('Sells', 'Product.id = Sells.Pid');
$this->db->join('Purchased', 'Product.id = Purchased.Pid');
$query = $this->db->get();
```

Comment: it works, but i face one challege, if sells table and purchased table are empty it still gives output, while i want to return nothing when sells and purchased are empty

Comment: In that case you would not use left joins.  Answer has been updated.